# Android StreetView compass mode coordinate-system change

Tags: android, google-street-view

I would like to develop an application to Samsung Galaxy Beam which has a built in projector. I would like to project streetview the similar way to the compass mode (when the device rotates the picture rotated too), but i need to rotate it by 90 degrees because the projector is on the top of the device. As I see, there is no API for streetview yet. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes, with this tutorial [link](http://jamiethompson.co.uk/web/2010/05/15/google-streetview-static-api/) i was able to download the streetview images, and do whatever i want with them.